# Why can't I use a dictionary named `dict` before assigning to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have multiple files that I need to load so I'm using a `dict` to shorten things. When I run I get a

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Error. How can I get this to work?

```
m1 = pygame.image.load(dict[1])
m2 = pygame.image.load(dict[2])
m3 = pygame.image.load(dict[3])
dict = {1: "walk1.png", 2: "walk2.png", 3: "walk3.png"}
playerxy = (375,130)
window.blit(m1, (playerxy))
```

Comment: Do you mean to assign `dict` prior to the references on the preceding lines? Try moving the 4th line before the 1st line.

Comment: This question currently **misleadingly distracts from** the canonical for an **unrelated problem** (using syntax that was not in the language when the question was asked). It was caused more or less by a typo, and only became popular in the first place because the specific failure mode was interesting to examine and describe in the answer.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Normally Python throws `NameError` if the variable is not defined:

```
>>> d[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

However, you've managed to stumble upon a name that already exists in Python.

Because [`dict` is the name of a built-in type in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) you are seeing what appears to be a strange error message, but in reality it is not.

The type of `dict` is a `type`. All types are objects in Python. Thus you are actually trying to index into the `type` object. This is why the error message says that the "'type' object is not subscriptable."

```
>>> type(dict)
<type 'type'>
>>> dict[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Note that you can blindly assign to the `dict` name, but you **really don't want to do that.** It's just going to cause you problems later.

```
>>> dict = {1:'a'}
>>> type(dict)
<class 'dict'>
>>> dict[1]
'a'
```

The true source of the problem is that you must assign variables prior to trying to use them. If you simply reorder the statements of your question, it will almost certainly work:

```
d = {1: "walk1.png", 2: "walk2.png", 3: "walk3.png"}
m1 = pygame.image.load(d[1])
m2 = pygame.image.load(d[2])
m3 = pygame.image.load(d[3])
playerxy = (375,130)
window.blit(m1, (playerxy))
```

Answer (score 53):

you should update to `python >= 3.9`
and everything will work well

Comment: This is a solution to an unrelated problem with type annotations that produces the same error; **not OP's issue**.

Comment: Actually, this was very useful to me! I updated from `python=3.8` to `python=3.9` and the problem was solved. It was complaining about `list` which was not subscriptable.

Comment: While possibly true, this is neither explaining anything nor offering a real solution. What if I need to stay with Python < 3.9?

Comment: @Mayou36 To stay with python3.8, you must change the code to support that version.
`list[str]` can't be used directly. Instead, import `List` - `from typing import List` and then use it in a similar way - `List[str]`

Comment: @maxandron sure, I am aware of this, but I meant actually to add this to the answer. Saying to "upgrade Python" is not really an answer. I would expect an explanation and possible solutions (i.e. upgrade Python OR do this and this)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460126/typeerror-type-object-is-not-subscriptable-in-a-function-signature for the question/answer that this answer addresses~

Comment: @AmirPourmand right; that's because you had a **different problem** from OP.

Answer (score 1):

For me I go the same error once I try to access model class attributes like if it was dictionary  `dimension['dimension_id']` though dimension type is
`app.models.evaluation.DimensionsEvaluation object` so I got the error

```
TypeError: 'DimensionsEvaluation' object is not subscriptable
```

to fix this I had to get the dictionary field from the model class using `.__dict__` and access my attribute normally like above:

```py
...
for dimension in evaluation_dimensions:
    print(f"\n dimension_id: {dimension['dimension_id']}\n") #TypeError: 'DimensionsEvaluation' object is not subscriptable


for dimension in evaluation_dimensions:
    dimension_dic = dimension.__dict__
    print(f"\n dimension_id: {dimension_dic['dimension_id']}\n") #dimension_id: 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

When I stumbled across this error, I had this function:

```py
def trainByDistribution(xs: pd.DataFrame, ys: pd.DataFrame, step) -> tuple[float]:
```

My idea was to create a function that takes two pandas dataframes and an integer and would return a tuple of floating-pointing numbers.

Like other answers have stated, in Python everything is objects, even classes themselves. Classes are in turn blueprint objects that can be used to generate new objects, and consequently classes can be assigned to variables, passed as arguments and programmatically constructed with `type()` function.

```py
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def __str__(self):
        return str(name) + str(age)
```

This class is equivalent to this:

```py
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.age = age
    self.name = name
def  __str__(self):
     return str(name) + str(age)
Person = type("Person, ("object",), {"__init__": __init__,
            "__str__": __str__})
```

This error "object is not subscriptable" appears when you pass to a function an object that doesn't support accessing values by indexing (doesn't overload the [] operator). Since the type of all classes is `<class "type">`:

```py
>>> type(Person)
<class "type">
```

then type object is not subscriptable means you pass class instead of an actual object. This could be more tricky though, in my function above I passed valid dataframes, and my error appeared because I attempted to annotate the return type as `tuple[float]`, and while this syntax should be legal to my knowledge, the interpreter understood this expression as if I wanted to index the tuple class itself.

## Conclusions

This error appears when:

- you pass class instead of an actual object to a function argument;
- you use the class name to index anything, including naming variables with class names.

You can take a look at this [tutorial by mCoding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWzMiaqnpkI) to find out more about classes as objects.

Comment: `tuple[float]` is valid syntax only after Python 3.9 in which a new feature called [generic alias type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#generic-alias-type) is added to support type parameters for builtin types. Before that, import `typing.Tuple` and use `Tuple[float]` instead. See also https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html?highlight=typing#typing.Tuple