# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
data_path = "/home/nikitha/Desktop/SOftmax/cifar-10-batches-bin/data_batch_1"

fo = open(data_path,'rb')
fo.seek(0)
fo.seek(0)
dict = (pickle.load(fo,encoding='bytes'))
l=np.array(dict[b'labels'])
d=np.array(dict[b'data'])
l=np.array(dict[b'labels'])
```

> TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

This is the above error I get when I run the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable when indexing in to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920955/typeerror-type-object-is-not-subscriptable-when-indexing-in-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, **dict** is an object of **type** 'type'.
 You can't use it as a variable.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26921030/6591278)

You're trying to assign 'type' to something, but 'type' already exists in python.

Comment: I am vering ity new to tensorflow and python,I t would be great if you point out where I went wrong in the above code by ciorrect