# "TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable" in a function signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, typeerror, type-hinting

Why am I receiving this error when I run this code?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                  
  File "main.py", line 13, in <module>                                                                                                                                              
    def twoSum(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:                                                                                                                    
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

```
nums = [4,5,6,7,8,9]
target = 13

def twoSum(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:
        dictionary = {}
        answer = []
 
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            secondNumber = target-nums[i]
            if(secondNumber in dictionary.keys()):
                secondIndex = nums.index(secondNumber)
                if(i != secondIndex):
                    return sorted([i, secondIndex])
                
            dictionary.update({nums[i]: i})

print(twoSum(nums, target))
```

Comment: not familiar with the syntax you're using..  don't you mean ```def twoSum(nums, target):```?

Comment: @ewong. It's type hints, and they're all the rage now

Comment: This syntax is supported from Python 3.9 onwards only

Comment: Related: [Using List/Tuple/etc. from typing vs directly referring type as list/tuple/etc](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39458193/7851470).

Comment: As other mentioned this will be supported in Python 3.9, but if you want to use this solution (like `list[int]`) earlier, you can do it by putting `from __future__ import annotations` as the first import of the module (available from Python 3.7+ because of  [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)).

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37087457

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**The following answer only applies to Python < 3.9**

The expression `list[int]` is attempting to subscript the object [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list), which is a class. Class objects are of the type of their metaclass, which is [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) in this case. Since `type` does not define a [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method, you can't do `list[...]`.

To do this correctly, you need to import [`typing.List`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.List) and use that instead of the built-in `list` in your type hints:

```
from typing import List

...


def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
```

If you want to avoid the extra import, you can simplify the type hints to exclude generics:

```
def twoSum(self, nums: list, target: int) -> list:
```

Alternatively, you can get rid of type hinting completely:

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
```

Comment: Typing hasn't used metaclasses since like 3.7 because typing code which used a different metaclass was impossible. `__class_getitem__` was added and is what is used to subscript types. Additionally your answer is completely wrong in Python 3.9+.

Comment: This just solved my problem. Ta a lot!

Comment: @masher. Always happy to hear when things work out. Good luck!

Comment: If anyone is arriving at this solution using Pydantic and Python3.8, this is it; check for `list, dict` types and convert them to `List, Dict,` solved for me.

Answer (score 18):

Lifting the comment from @Nerxis into an answer.

For Python 3.7 and 3.8, add:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
```

as your first import into your module.

While the accepted answer of using `List` instead of `list` is fine, it won't help you when you need to do `pd.Series[np.int64]`.  Use the above instead.

Answer (score 7):

### Summary

The part of the code that says `-> list[int]` is a *type annotation* for the return type of the function. It is a special notation that can be used **by third-party tools** to do some basic static type-checking on the code. The **only** effect it has on the code, as far as Python itself is concerned, is to add some metadata to the function:

```
>>> def example() -> list[int]:
...     pass
... 
>>> 'return' in example.__annotations__
True
```

Python itself **will not** do any type checking:

```
>>> type(example()) # definitely did not give a list of integers!
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Similarly, the `: list[int]` part is a type annotation for the `nums` parameter for `twoSum`.

Depending on the Python version, this specific annotation may not be accepted.

#### Python 3.9 and above

The error is not reproducible. `-> list[int]` declares that the function is intended to return a list that contains all integer values, and `: list[int]` declares that another such list should be passed in for `nums`. These hints allow third-party tools like MyPy to look for problems before the code is compiled or run.

#### Python 3.7 or 3.8

This annotation is not accepted as-is. There are two workarounds:

1. Use a `__future__` import, to access the "postponed evaluation of annotations" behaviour described in [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/):

```
# At the top of the code, along with the other `import`s
from __future__ import annotations
```

2. Use the corresponding class defined in the standard library `typing` module:

```
# At the top of the code
from typing import List

# when annotating the function
def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
```

Note the capital L in `List`.

#### Python 3.5 and 3.6

The `__future__` annotation is not supported. Use the `typing` module.

#### Python 3.4 and below

Type annotations are not supported at all. Simply remove them:

```
def twoSum(self, nums, target):
```

Again, remember that **Python itself does not do anything meaningful with the annotations**. They will not cause the code to raise exceptions for invalid parameters, convert them to the correct type, or anything else like that. They are **only** for third-party tools, and **completely optional** unless some other third-party tool is forcing their use.

Answer (score 4):

The answer given above by "Mad Physicist" works, but this page on new features in 3.9 suggests that "list[int]" should also work.

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html

But it doesn't work for me.  Maybe mypy doesn't yet support this feature of 3.9.

Comment: My code runs fine with list[int] in 3.9 (no runtime error), but still doesn't type check correctly with mypy.

Comment: Same here, `list[int]` works fine in 3.9, but raises the OP's error under Python3.8 (specifically the AWS Lambda Python3.8 runtime).

Comment: In a venv \w python3 version `3.9.2`, I still get the error