# What is type object is not subscriptable?

Tags: python

I teaching myself python so very much a beginner. This was a problem given to me to see if can solve it. Compare a list of numbers to one integer and if the last number in the list is higher than the lone integer it should return the string "Higher" and "Smaller" if it Smaller. It is the same number it should return the first integer in the list. This is the code I have so far. I is for interation which means it will look through the list, right? I understand the conditionals: if, else and then the first index position is O. But what does "type object not subscriptable" mean?

```
def problem1(aList, number):
    for i in aList:
        if i in range [aList] > number:
            return ("Larger")
        if i in range [aList] < number:
            return ("Smaller")
        else:
            return aList[0]
```

Comment: `range` is a type, just like `int` , `str`, `list`, etc. To construct a range object, you must *call the range constructor*, e.g. `range(10)`. What did you *expect* `rang[aList]` to do? It isn't clear, but that is what causes the error.

Comment: `if i in range [aList] > number` doesn't make any sense. Can you explain in English what operation you were trying to perform there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable when indexing in to a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26920955/typeerror-type-object-is-not-subscriptable-when-indexing-in-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

`type object not subscriptable` is, admittedly, a bit cryptic. `var[key]` and is usable on every object that implements the `__getitem__` method. The builtin type doing that is the dictionary (`dict` in Python). The [builtin `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is not a dict, but a type, and types do not implement that method. The error you are getting basically means "sorry, but I couldn't find a **getitem** method for this type". In fact you don't even need `range()` and the for loop for you task. Just use iterable indexing. To get the last item of an iterable, you write -1 instead of 0 for the first element. And you don't need to wrap your return value into parentheses:

```py
def problem1(aList, number):
    if aList[-1] > number:
        return "Larger"
    elif aList[-1] < number:
            return "Smaller"
    else:
        return aList[0]
```

Comment: What's so cryptic about the error? You are trying to slice an object which is not subscriptable, in this case it's a type (`range`)...

Comment: @Tomerikoo i mean for a python beginner it's cryptic, not for me of course  ...